# Javascript syntax checker for Text Area text?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Im working on a project and one of the requirements is that users can write their own javascript code, on a simple text area component.

This is easy, but I have to validate the syntax, something like 'error: missing ; at the end'... like most syntax checkers do.

I dont want to develop it, cause it would take a lot of time.

Does anybody know if a plugin exists for that?
I found one called Javascript Lint but it is a .exe file and it doesnt have native integration with Java (its a java ee project, jsp files, etc)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple top-down parser: https://github.com/douglascrockford/TDOP/blob/master/parse.js.

A more complicated parser is JSLint: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint. JSLint is half parser, have C-style "lint" tool (for checking for common mistakes), but you can just make use of the parser half by not reporting 'lint' results to your users. You can also turn off all of the "lint" checks.

The major difference is that JSLint will do things like checking that variables are defined and in scope and checking for other mistakes/common bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not critical, you can ask users to paste their data in http://www.jslint.com/ (Doug Crockford's site) and it displays the errors within the JSON.

We had used YUI in our JS application, so we used YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(your textarea's json content) to validate the user's Json. However, we were never able to give them an exact list of errors within the Json, we could only tell them if it was valid Json.

Thanks